# Copy file from Docker container to Host using Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I'm using a docker container for compiling a code that I many not necessarily want to dockerize. I have set up an image with the necessary build tools but I would like to get the compiled file somehow out of the container without using the `docker cp container:/file host/file` command. In other words, I would like automate this process so that after build is completed, the generated files would be copied to the host.

Can the copy command in Dockerfile `COPY <source> <target>` be used for this purpose? If no, then what is the solution?

Comment: What about [Docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)?

Comment: @KunalNagpal: I am asking specifically about Copying

Comment: Yes. After the in-container compilation is done, the build result(s) can be placed in the mounted directory, becoming available to the underlying host. This is also how other Docker-based hosting platforms export application logs from the running container, etc.

Comment: @KunalNagpal: No, not using volumes (--mount, -v command). Just something that copies the file from the container to host without forcing the user to add any configuration

Comment: why you don't use the docker scale? as ı understood you, you want to copy the container

Comment: @dılosürücü Can you show me an example?

Comment: @dılosürücü: No I don't want to copy the container

Comment: actually  ı don't understand exactly what do you want

Comment: Volumes won't work as they're only available at container run time, and you want to do this at image build time if I understand you correctly.

Comment: @HansKilian: Exactly!

Comment: @HansKilian: However, I can also run the container for one time to compile the code, but need to get file out of it.

Comment: The linked question suggests `docker create`ing a container that you can `docker cp` out of.  You could also build an image with just the tools but not the source code, and `docker run` the compiler with the source and output directories bind-mounted with `-v` options (this is how for instance Jenkins works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't copy from a build process to the host context using COPY.

If you need the image and also the executable on the host, then the only way I can think of is a server to push the executable to. That can be something like SSH where you use `scp` to copy it. Or you could use a web server and use `curl` to do a `POST` of the file. Lots of options, but they all require a server you can send the executable to.

Another option is (like you say yourself) to run the image after you've built it and then use `docker cp` to copy the file from the container to the host.